# hive row wise count by the type in data

Tags: hiveql

```
h1      h2      h3      h4      h5      h6      h7      h8
U       U       NULL    U       Y       NULL    Y       X
U       NULL    U       U       Y       Y       X       X
U       U       U       NULL    U       NULL    Y       NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
X       V       U       U       Y       NULL    Z       X
Y       X       NULL    X       Y       Z       U
X       NULL    U       NULL    NULL    U       Z       Y
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Above data set is has 8 columns h1,h2,h3......h8. If all the all the column is NULL then the count is 0. If at least one column has value then the count is 1.
Like the first row has a count of 6.(do not consider null values).

And here X= boy,v= girl, u= wife, z=husbend, y= head. So, how can we find the count by type (ex. boy or wife or head etc) for every row-wise. Like how many wife and how many husbands or how many girls are there?

Comment: Please show the desired result for the shown sample data.

Comment: this is the data set collected by each lead for each household member for a particular household. so here eight column are representing the eight member of a single household and each rows value is for different different household. so my question is how can i count the household member by type? like how many are wife and how many are head of the hosehold are present over here?

Comment: What output would you want to see for the data example you have provided in your question?

Comment: the type and the count

Comment: like    U 234 and Y 675 thats the result i wanted

Comment: How does "U 234 and Y 675" match the sample data given in the question? I cannot see the connection.

Comment: its just a example.....U 234(that is the count no would be here) it may be U 10

Comment: Could you please provide the output you would like to see for the given data example? Apart from trying to describe the logic of your goal more clearly, this is the minimum effort that can be expected to be spent by you.

Comment: how can i show you the output i still dont know the code yet how can i show you the output? i just given you the problem statement and now i need the right code to get that expected result as i mentioned.

Comment: Just use the editor and type what you would want to see as output. Kind of ascii art. You can apply the logic of what you want to code to your own sample data, can't you? If you cannot do that, then the logic is not even clear to you. How would you expect the readers in this community to then get what you mean? Please make up a pair of sample input and desired output; better yet several pairs.